# throw new Error('bot.startConversationWithUser(): missing serviceUrl.');

Tags: javascript, node.js, botkit

```
controller.hears('dm me', 'message', async(bot, message) => {
        await bot.startConversationWithUser(message.reference);
        await bot.say('Hello! (in private)');
    });
```

I'm using botkit to send message on Slack but I'm getting this error

```
throw new Error('bot.startConversationWithUser(): missing serviceUrl.');
                      ^

Error: bot.startConversationWithUser(): missing serviceUrl.
    at SlackBotWorker
```

I tried console.log(message.reference), its showing me serviceUrl: undefined

Comment: You will need to do some more debugging to figure out why `serviceUrl` is missing

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". Code rarely summarizes the problem.